# Как узнать размер объекта?

Tags: c#

Какие есть способы получить размер объекта в памяти? Можно не обязательно в рантайме (кодом).

Comment: А что такое размер объекта? Если, например, объект содержит ссылки на другие объекты, те объекты считать?

Comment: @VladD Хороший вопрос. Скорее считать чем нет. Я больше думал о коллекциях.

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov, способ с WinDBG покажет Вам полный размер объекта, т.е. его размер + сумма размеров всех внутренних объектов. Способ с `BinaryFormatter` тоже покажет суммарный размер. На крайний случай в WinDBG можно посмотреть размер связанных объектов отдельно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно использовать [WinDBG](http://www.windbg.org/) с [psscor4.dll](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21255) для платформы .NET (ещё есть [Son of Strike](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764(v=vs.110).aspx) но для Вашей задачи достаточно psscor4 (для CLR версии 2.* нужно взять psscor2)).

1. Запускаем WinDbg от имени администратора желательно.
2. Аттачимся к нашему процессу.
3. Загружаем psscor4: `.load C:\Symbols\Psscor4\x86\x86\psscor4.dll` - путь тут нужно подставить свой.
4. Ищете Ваш объект. Тут есть несколько способов, например, самый простой для простых тестов памяти это выполнить команду `!DumpHeap` и вы увидите например такое:
   [image: результат !DumpHeap]
5. Дальше выполняем команду `!DumpHeap /d -mt 00414da0`, где `00414da0` - адрес Вашего объекта. И видим:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. И последний шаг (в этом простом примере): это выполнить команду получения размера объекта по его адресу: `!objsize 0df73294`, где `0df73294` - адрес объекта. И видим:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код для теста:

```
public static class Program
{
  private static void Main()
  {
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject
    {
      S = "1234567895555555555555555555555555555555",
      Type = 0
    };

    Console.ReadKey(); // не забудьте приаттачится в нужный момент.

    Console.WriteLine(myObject);
  }
}

public class MyObject
{
  public int Type { get; set; }
  public string S { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

1. [Записать в мемори стрим и измерить его.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173599/1304136)
2. [Используя <s>адские хаки</s> указатели добраться до метаинформации типа CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1128674/1304136)
3. [sizeof() для стандартных типов и пользовательских структур без ссылок на референсные типы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx) (иначе будет возвращаться размер указателя).
4. Воспользоваться профайлером.

Первые три способа работают в рантайме.

Comment: Спасибо! Вот в первом случае мы получим не размер в памяти, а сколько памяти нужно для представления объекта в десериализованном виде, могут получиться разные цифры. Поковырялся с профайлером, там как-то интуитивно приходится искать по снимку памяти. Можно ошибиться с объектом, например несколько объектов одного типа, какой из них нужный?

Answer (score 2):

Можно с [ClrMD](https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd) поиграться, сделать дамп процесса и пройтись по куче [Walking Managed Objects in the Process](https://github.com/microsoft/clrmd/blob/master/doc/GettingStarted.md#walking-managed-objects-in-the-process)